# Webpack: adding files to bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm working on a project that is built as an isomorphic React app using  Redux, and webpack as well. I'm new to all of these technologies, and I would like to load 2 files into webpack for syntax highlighting in one of my react components.

In addition to these technologies the project is also built using [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to manage the document head.

Having not used webpack all that much before I tried adding the reference to my two files in the head and body blocks as such:

```
<script src="path/to/file/fileName.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

however that throws the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I've also tried adding it to my React Helmet config as a script...

```
      script: [
        {"src": "path/to/file/fileName.js", "type": "text/javascript"}
      ],
```

...but I'm getting the same error

How can I load this file into my webpack bundle so it is available across the app without it having to be required by a specific component?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `import` or `require` in your code and webpack add that file to bundle. File will be AMD or [Common.js module](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1).